# Moving back to the the previous fragment tab (KEYCODE_BACK)

Tags: android, fragment, keycode

Moving back to the previous fragment tab (KEYCODE_BACK)
I have something like 
TAB
       FA – FB –FC - FD

How can I implement something that when the back button is pressed it moves to the previous fragment i.e. from FD-->FC and from FC-->FB and from FB-->FA (TAB)

With the code below it moves from FD-->FB and from FC-->FA how can I correct this.

Thank you

```
    View.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);//Called in Fragment D
    View.requestFocus();
    View.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();     
                    Fragment fragment = new FragmentC(); //move to previous fragment (FC)
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.my_container, fragment)
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);       
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    return true;
                }

                else {

                    return false;
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `addToBackstack` to open new Fragments, it should work without the keyback listener.  The fragmentTransaction manages this for you.

Comment: I will take a look at that Thanks